# How to build clang compiler-rt on Windows linked against dynamic Visual C++ runtimes?

Tags: qt, visual-c++, llvm-clang, address-sanitizer, clang-cl

I want to use clang-cl with address sanitizers on Windows. When trying with the prebuilt llvm/clang packages from the official installers, I get linker errors because my application needs linking to the dynamic CRT (/MD) instead of the static CRT (/MT, the packages in the llvm/clang installers have compiler-rt built with this).

I want to use this with Qt, because I did not manage to build Qt itself with /MT .

According to [these](https://llvm.org/devmtg/2014-10/Slides/ASan%20for%20Windows.pdf) slides from a google engineer, building compiler-rt/asan with /MT is possible.

What do I have to change compared to [these instructions](https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) when building llvm/clang in order to build compiler-rt with /MT ?

Comment: /MT and /MD pertain to MS Visual C++. Not even sure if asking question like that makes it clearer to everybody.

Comment: Even worse, I had mixed up the names of the switches ... Hopefully the title now fits better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my linker errors had [another](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36724) reason.

To find the required libraries, build a small hello-world app with the following command, inspect the resulting linker command and link to the required libraries explicitly:

```
clang-cl -v -fsanitize=address /MD test.cpp
```

[PR35343](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35343) (currently unresolved) is about supporting automatic linking of sanitizer libs in lld-link, like it is done on other platforms.